# SSH-add is not persistent event though ssh-agent is started

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I did ssh-add. During the session it works fine, but when I exit and reconnect to the server with ssh it does not work anymore ssh-add -l says: no identities.

I do start the ssh-agent in my .bash_profile using eval $(ssh-agent).

Any ideas what I can do to keep the identities?

**// EDIT** 
So here is my scenario. I am connecting to my web-space using ssh. I want to pull data from github using git pull. I added the connection to github and git pull works fine. But it asks for the passphrase. Doing a ssh-add adn adding the passphrase stops that, but only for the current session.

I have to start the ssh-agent using something like `eval $(ssh-agent)` because it does not autostart on the server.

The main problem I am having is, that I need a script to do the git pull which is invoked by a request from github, so I can not give it the passphrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're spawning the agent when your session starts, then it'll die when you disconnect. You could connect to a screen or byobu/tmux server which keeps the agent alive (you can skip an instance of bash if you connect like `ssh user@hostname -t 'byobu'`).

Otherwise, have the agent come up when the machine boots so your session comings and goings don't affect it.

Edit: you can also forward your agent from your *local* machine. This works very well if you happen to have the same keys available on both machines. Try something like this in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host whatever
    Hostname        whatever.com
    User            username
    ForwardAgent    yes
```

You invoke this with `ssh whatever`, in case you are not familiar with that config file.

Comment: Hey, sadly I am connecting to a server and this server needs to save the identity so I have limited influence.

I have different keys, so the forwarding does not work either.

I do not really understand if the other things would work for me. I edited the question, maybe that gives you a better idea of what I am trying to achive.

Comment: If it's pull-only then you can use a deploy key (read only) in GitHub. Create one at `https://github.com/<username>/<project>/admin/keys` and put the corresponding private half on your webserver. You'll create it without a passphrase, but the key is limited in scope and read-only.

Comment: "You invoke this with ssh whatever, ..."  
Yes, or directly using the username like this:  
    `ssh username@host`
i.e.
    `ssh max@domain.com`